# running naturaldocs before on git add

Tags: git

I have just discovered the joys of http://www.naturaldocs.org/. I am wondering how I can run my naturaldocs command `~/bin/NaturalDocs -i ~/Sites/app -o HTML ~/Sites/app/docs -p ~/Projects/app` automatically when I actually run `~/Sites/appgit add .`

I am looking at the sample git hooks, and from its name, the pre-applypatch hook seems right for this, but the git docs indicate that this hook is run after the patch is applied but before the commit is made. My intent, of course, is to generate documentation via naturaldocs and then add that newly generated documentation to git automatically. Suggestions?

Comment: OT, but what's the point of tracking auto-generated docs?

Comment: because that way the comments get pushed to the remote repository, and from there to the production site where I want the comments to be available. Otherwise, the auto-generated docs remain only on my computer in my git repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pre-commit` hook to run the naturaldocs and get them added during commit (i.e when you do `git commit`)

Comment: would it be as simple as `#!/bin/sh\n~/bin/NaturalDocs -i ~/Sites/app -o HTML ~/Sites/app/docs -p ~/Projects/app`?